# Mule 3.7 - Bulk update mode for stored procedures in database

Tags: mule, mule-component

Is there a way I can have a bulk mode when I am using a stored procedure in Mule's Database component. It looks like the current version only supports it for Parameterized queries. Is there any work around available? I am trying something similar as below.

```
<db:insert config-ref="" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query>
            <![CDATA[INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, BILLING_NUMBER__C, TYPE)  
            VALUES (#[payload.Id], #[payload.Billing_Number__c], #[payload.type]);]]>
        </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

But i want to replace the query with a stored procedure for which I do not see the bulkMode flag. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem. It looks like I can still do a bulk update using a stored procedure (using the new db component) by chosing the "Update" function, but using a dynamic query which is a stored-procedure. It allows me to check the Bulk-Update option and accepts an array as an input.

```
<db:update config-ref="L360_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Sync_LoanAppDB">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[${sp_name}]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:update>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear possible to set IN and OUT parameters this way however. Was this not something you had to do, or did you perhaps find a way around it?

Comment: This is my work around, since I need to use an SP as a bulk update query. You can provide the arguments as MEL expressions in your property file, if that's something you would like to do. For eg,sp.call=call sp_name(Arg1,Arg2,etc). If there are any out arguments, you will receive the value as a list of maps in the output. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Stored proc call worked in Update mode. It worked in Batch commit as well. Not sure why did they not mention anything about this in Mule documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try similar to this:

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Call Stored Procedure Function">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[CALL callFunction(:name,:id_serv);]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="display_name" type="VARCHAR" value="#[payload.name]"/>
            <db:out-param name="id_serv" type="INTEGER"/>
        </db:stored-procedure>
</foreach>
```

Or you can change the foreach into a batch step of Batch Processing of Mule.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am actually trying to avoid issuing multiple statements to the database. In previous versions of mule with the jdbc:endpoint, you could issue a batch / bulk update by just providing a list of objects to the jdbc:outbound (includeing stored procs) is there a substitute for that?

Comment: You can still use that but that is already deprecated. If you want to use a list of objects then you can inject to the value the #[payload] which is a List. then change the type as "JAVA_OBJECT" or "ARRAY". <db:in-param name="ListName" type="JAVA_OBJECT" value="#[payload]"/>

Comment: Thank you. I kind of found a work-around for this. Please refer my answer.